# raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed') when try to schedule "mongoimport" tasks

Tags: concurrency, python-asyncio, mongoimport

Here is a weird err, I encountered when I try to use "asyncio" to schedule "mongoimport" task. Once I started mongod service, and pasted commands I generated on terminal, it worked. However, when I try to use python3.4 asyncio，problems come:

```
  File "/Users/wangyi/Documents/workspace/Math/machine_learning/ditech/io/collect.py", line 100, in <module>
    parse_train_data()
  File "/Users/wangyi/Documents/workspace/Math/machine_learning/ditech/io/collect.py", line 95, in parse_train_data
    call_in_background(*targets)
  File "/Users/wangyi/Documents/workspace/Math/machine_learning/ditech/io/collect.py", line 19, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **keywords)
  File "/Users/wangyi/Documents/workspace/Math/machine_learning/ditech/io/collect.py", line 41, in call_in_background
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*targets, loop=loop))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 567, in gather
    fut = async(arg, loop=loop)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 511, in async
    task = loop.create_task(coro_or_future)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 211, in create_task
    self._check_closed()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 265, in _check_closed
    raise RuntimeError('Event loop is closed')
RuntimeError: Event loop is closed
```

Here is my snippet of codes:

```
def parse_train_data():

    commandtpl = "mongoimport --host=127.0.0.1 -d DiDitech -c {table} -f {fields}  --type tsv --file {target}"

    for tb in tables:
        tasks = list(map(lambda t: commandtpl.format(table=tb, fields=','.join(fields[tb]), target=t), train_dest[tb]))
        print('commands of %s:' % tb)
        print('' + '\n'.join(tasks))
        targets = [get_lines(ob) for ob in tasks]
        call_in_background(*targets)
```

call_in_background is light wrapper with timmer upon `run_util_complete` of (asyncio.gather(*targets)).  targets are defined as coros as stated in PEP.

```
def call_in_background(*targets):
...
    loop = get_loop()
    print(loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*targets, loop=loop, return_exceptions=True)))
    #loop.close()

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_lines(shell_command):
    task = yield from asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(shell_command,
            stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

    return (yield from task.communicate())[0].splitlines()
```

Comment: What does `call_in_background` look like? Does it close the loop? Please edit the question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @dirn yes it will close the loop once run_until_complete returns. Should I call the author of asyncio Anrew for help?

Comment: That's your problem. Don't close the loop until you're done with it.

Comment: Hi @dirn I have updated my post and it seems irregular because every example in python doc will end up with 'loop.close'. How should I use it correctly?

Comment: The examples close the loop at the end of the example. Not in the middle of a for loop. With `loop.close()` commented out, are you still getting the same error?

Comment: @dirn oh you reminds me ! thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Now I change the codes

```
...

    flag = False
    if loop is None:
        loop = get_loop()
        flag = True
    print(loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.gather(*targets, loop=loop, return_exceptions=True)))

    if flag == False:
        loop.close()
```

and it works thanks finally with rearranging codes structure. Thx!!!

```
2016-06-28T16:39:59.128+0800    connected to: 127.0.0.1
2016-06-28T16:39:59.136+0800    imported 279 documents
2016-06-28T16:39:59.130+0800    connected to: 127.0.0.1
2016-06-28T16:39:59.145+0800    imported 66 documents
2016-06-28T16:39:59.134+0800    connected to: 127.0.0.1
2016-06-28T16:39:59.142+0800    imported 288 documents
2016-06-28T16:39:59.140+0800    connected to: 127.0.0.1
2016-06-28T16:39:59.148+0800    imported 285 documents
```